# Confused about following step from Ruby on Rails Guide website

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a totally new to learn rails and just start this Ruby on Rails Guide website.
And, i am a little confused when I following some step.

1.Why "redirect_to @post" will get "show action"?
2.Why we need use "index action" to list all posts? 
3.When we use "<%= link_to "My Blog", controller: "posts" %>", I know it will link to posts controller, but don't know why will display index action which list all posts?

Thanks.

Comment: For 1. refer to [Rails resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default). 2. It's convention. Actually, it's very convenient convention. 3. `index` action is default if you omit action parameter.

Comment: It's all about convention over configuration. `redirect_to` is smart enough to determine if single record or a collection of records is given as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

1. "show" action is to display a object detailed information, and the object is @post.
2. "index" action is to display one sort of resources.
3. You can use the default action, but you can customize it at well, like below:

> .<%= link_to "Blog", {:action => "any_action", :controller 
>        "posts_or_any_controller"}, {:method => :get} %>